# Why doesn't `const int ci = 2; std::forward<int>(ci);` work and how to fix / workaround it?

Tags: c++, c++11, perfect-forwarding

Simple question, why doesn't [the following](http://ideone.com/tmfiV) work (implying a copy of `ci`)?

```
#include <utility>

int main(){
  const int ci = 2;
  std::forward<int>(ci);
}
```

> prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
>   prog.cpp:6:23: error: no matching function for call to 'forward(const int&)'

The problem manifested itself while writing some template stuff, where I have a simple holder type as follows. To avoid unnecessary copies, I use perfect forwarding where possible, but that turns out to be the root of the problem it seems.

```
template<class T>
struct holder{
    T value;

    holder(T&& val)
        : value(std::forward<T>(val))
    {}
};

template<class T>
holder<T> hold(T&& val){
    // T will be deduced as int, because literal `5` is a prvalue
    // which can be bound to `int&&`
    return holder<T>(std::forward<T>(val));
}

template<class T>
void foo(holder<T> const& h)
{
    std::tuple<T> t;  // contrived, actual function takes more parameters
    std::get<0>(t) = std::forward<T>(h.value); // h.value is `const T`
}

int main(){
    foo(hold(5));
}
```

If any further information is needed, please let me know.
Any idea to circumvent this problem is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should do this: `template <class T> struct holder { holder(T val) : value(std::move(val)){} }; template <class T> holder<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type> hold(T val) { return holder<T>(std::move(val)); }` (Yes I'm aware that looks jumbly. :))

Comment: @GMan: But I don't want to remove the reference. :(

Comment: Then you call it as `hold(std::ref(x));`. :P

Comment: @GMan: Eww. ;/ Seems I need to explain what I'm trying to do. I'm currently trying to implement positional parameters, like `void foo(param_pack<int,int> p){...} /*...*/ foo((_2 = some_var, _1 = 1));`. Contrived example, but should bring my intent across. Sadly, I'm running into problem after problem with this. :( Now it's the references, which break when you try to move them: http://ideone.com/Vx0Jp

Comment: Oh, wait. I just got a fine idea to work around that problem~ Partial specializations ftw.

Comment: I was going to suggest that, but I've tried to avoid specializations as of late, if possible. (But not religiously, so I'd say go for it.)

Comment: @GMan: Why are you trying to avoid specializations? And *special* reason? :)

Comment: I've just found in the past when I'm writing generic code and I say, "it's not working with this type...specialize!" it ends up biting me because it wasn't the *type* in particular that was the problem, but the interaction with an entire set of types satisfying some concept. So if I'm having a problem like yours, it would be better to capture the concept that's the issue, not the type (or type class) in particular. But sometimes (perhaps often times) it really is just a fundamental type that needs special handing.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This:

```
#include <utility>

int main(){
  const int ci = 2;
  std::forward<int>(ci);
}
```

doesn't work because you can't implicitly cast away `const`.  `std::forward<T>(u)` should be read as:

> Forward `u` as a `T`.

You are attempting to say:

```
Forward an lvalue `const int` as an rvalue `int`.
```

which throws away the `const`.  To avoid throwing away the `const` you could:

```
#include <utility>

int main(){
  const int ci = 2;
  std::forward<const int>(ci);
}
```

which says:

```
Forward an lvalue `const int` as an rvalue `const int`.
```

In your code:

```
template<class T>
void foo(holder<T> const& h)
{
    std::tuple<T> t;  // contrived, actual function takes more parameters
    std::get<0>(t) = std::forward<T>(h.value); // h.value is `const T`
}
```

the `const` qualifier on `h` impacts the data member selection expression `h.value`.  `h.value` is a `const` lvalue `int`.  You can use `forward` to change that into a `const` rvalue `int`, or you could use `forward` to pass it on unchanged (as a `const` lvalue `int`).  You *could* even use `forward` to add `volatile` (though I can't think of a good reason to).

In your example, I'm seeing no reason to use `forward` at all (unless you take the `const` off of `h`).

```
    std::get<0>(t) = h.value; // h.value is `const T`
```

Your comment is even still correct.

It's a dry read, but [N2951](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2951.html) surveys what you can and can not do with `forward` and why.  This was modified by [N3143](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3143.html) just prior to standardization, but the use cases and rationale from are still valid and unchanged in the final N3143 formulation.

Things you can do with `forward`:

- You can forward an lvalue as an lvalue.
- You can forward an lvalue as an rvalue.
- You can forward an rvalue as an rvalue.
- You can forward less cv-qualified expressions to more cv-qualified expressions.
- You can forward expressions of derived type to an accessible, unambiguous base type.

Things you can **not** do with `forward`:

- You can not forward an rvalue as an lvalue.
- You can not forward more cv-qualified expressions to less cv-qualified expressions.
- You can not forward arbitrary type conversions (e.g. forward an `int` as a `double`).

Comment: Thanks for this extensive answer. Is there any way to "save" the forwardability of a value? Like I said in my comment on the question itself, I'm trying to implement positional parameters, and I'd like to forward all parameters like they were directly passed into the function. [Here](http://ideone.com/jeprD) is the full code I currently have (~300 LoC), even though GCC doesn't seem to like my SFINAE trickery on `switch_`.

Comment: I already found a few limitations in my system, such as that I can't bind temporaries of type `T` to `T const&` or `T&&` in the `param_pack` without getting dangling references. Is there any way to fix / improve that (if you're willing to wade through the code)?

Comment: @Xeo:  I'm unsure.  But I was able to fix your code up such that it runs on clang/libc++.  `std::move(pos::template switch_<0>(arg1, arg2, arg3).value` (add "template" 3 places).  Make param_pack BoundList constructor less generic:  `template<class B1, class B2, class B3> param_pack(bound_list<B1, B2, B3>&& bl)`.  With those changes your code runs for me and outputs:  `Value ctor
Move ctor
Move ctor
Move ctor
Copy ctor
Move ctor
Move ctor
hi 3 1
Dtor
Dtor`

Comment: D'oh, the dreaded nested template specifier! Thanks for the fix. Actually, the code I linked wasn't the most up-to-date, but I noticed that too late. I already made the change to the ctor, as the `bound_list` will only ever be a temporary anyways. The output is the same for me on VS11, but I'd like to get that one copy out. Sadly, step-into doesn't really help for VS11, as the relevant function where it happens is deeply burried inside a macro to simulate variadic templates. :( For anyone reading this and being interested, [here](http://ideone.com/iQcDW) is the fixed code for GCC.