# Why does std::forward have two overloads?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, rvalue, perfect-forwarding

Given the following reference collapsing rules

- `T& &` --> `T&`
- `T&& &` --> `T&`
- `T& &&` --> `T&`
- `T&& &&` --> `T&&`

The third and fourth rule imply that `T(ref qualifer) &&` is the identity transformation, i.e. `T&` stays at `T&` and `T&&` stays at `T&&`. Why do we have two overloads for `std::forward`? Couldn't the following definition serve all purposes?

```
template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_const<T>::value>>
T&& forward(const typename std::remove_reference<T>::type& val) {
    return static_cast<T&&>(const_cast<T&&>(val));
}
```

Here the only purpose the `const std::remove_reference<T>&` serves is to not make copies. And the `enable_if` helps ensure that the function is only called on non const values. I'm not entirely sure whether the `const_cast` is needed since it's not the reference itself that's const.

Since `forward` is always called with explicit template parameters there are two cases we need to consider:

1. `forward<Type&>(val)` Here the type of `T` in `forward` will be `T&` and therefore the return type will be the identity transformation to `T&`
2. `forward<Type&&>(val)` Here the type of `T` in `forward` will be `T&&` and therefore the return type will be the identity transformation to `T&&`

So then why do we need two overloads as described in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward?

**Note**: I am not sure if `std::forward` is ever used with `const` types, but I disabled `forward` in that case, because I have never seen it used like that. Also move semantics don't really make sense in that case either.

Comment: Becuase rvalue can't be bound to `val` if there's no the 2nd overload?

Comment: @songyuanyao whoops, I had a const in there earlier, but somehow decided to remove it...

Comment: The example you give cannot bind to rvalues (see [this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b0ae1eaf909513e0))

Comment: @Curious Using `const_cast` is dangerous. If the argument passed is a real `const` it leads to UB.

Comment: @songyuanyao: But he disables the definition if it is `const`, so we can assume it is not const? I don't know why he has a `const_cast` there then, probably it can just be a `static_cast`.

Comment: You may find Howard's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29135698/how-does-stdforward-receive-the-correct-argument) an interesting read.

Comment: @songyuanyao Thats why I used the `enable_if_t`

Comment: @ChrisBeck because the function reference argument itself is `const`, so just to remove that constness

Comment: @ChrisBeck or maybe I misunderstood the meaning of `const T&` to mean that the reference itself is const rather than the pointed to object being const.

Comment: I see so basically what you are saying is: "If this is a non const thing, that can bind to `const T &`, then `std::forward` of it should return an r-value-reference." (Since that's basically what it had to be)

Comment: Don't you also need a definition for the case when it is `const` ? Maybe I misunderstood

Comment: @ChrisBeck You mean a definition of std::forward for the case when the passed in object is const?  I have never seen it used like that so I disabled it...

Comment: So what does yours do in a case like this: `void f(const T & t) { g(std::forward<const T&>(t)); `? I guess it doesn't compile? If I understood right then the original one will still work, but maybe I'm wrong about that. Maybe a more realistic case is, I start with a `const T &`, and pass it via a forwarding reference into some function, where `std::forward` is applied.

Comment: @ChrisBeck that will compile because the reference itself is not const... let me think about this for one more minute though...

Comment: @ChrisBeck I guess that is why the 2 overloads are needed?  to prevent a user from using the function like that?  Since that version would work with `const` values as well, but I do not see why that would be an issue.  Maybe because `const Type&&` doesn't really make sense?  Although `std::forward` allows that type.

Comment: I guess I don't know, I never thought about implementing `std::forward`, I just kind of got used to what it does

Comment: @ChrisBeck same here!

Comment: Idk, I have to go, I will check back later

Comment: I don't even know what your version is trying to do; that `static_cast` casts away constness and will never compile.

Comment: The answer is in the link from @WhozCraig, and also in the cppreference.com docs. It's basically not about what happens when you use `forward` as recommended. It's about unusual cases that could be encountered accidentally. One of them would be `forward<T&>(function_returning_t())`. In this case, your version (minus the `const` issues) would effectively cast the return from the function to an lvalue; the standard one is specified to issue a compile time error.

Comment: See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2951.html. Use Case #D

Comment: Got the above link from this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283616/why-doesnt-const-int-ci-2-stdforwardintci-work-and-how-to-fix-wor

Comment: Also, it's called "perfect forwarding" because it's supposed to be... well, as close to perfect as possible. It has to forward `const` lvalues and rvalues just as well. What the destination does with them is not `forward`'s business.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A good place to start would be Howard Hinnant's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29135875/2069064) and [paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2951.html) on `std::forward()`.

---

Your implementation handles all the *normal* use-cases correctly (`T& --> T&`, `T const& --> T const&`, and `T&& --> T&&`). What it fails to handle are common and easy-to-make errors, errors which would be very difficult to debug in your implementation but fail to compile with `std::forward()`.

Given these definitions:

```
struct Object { };

template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_const<T>::value>>
T&& my_forward(const typename std::remove_reference<T>::type& val) {
    return static_cast<T&&>(const_cast<T&&>(val));
}

template <class T>
void foo(T&& ) { }
```

I can pass non-`const` references to `const` objects, both of the lvalue variety:

```
const Object o{};
foo(my_forward<Object&>(o));    // ok?? calls foo<Object&>
foo(std::forward<Object&>(o));  // error
```

and the rvalue variety:

```
const Object o{};
foo(my_forward<Object>(o));    // ok?? calls foo<Object>
foo(std::forward<Object>(o));  // error
```

I can pass lvalue references to rvalues:

```
foo(my_forward<Object&>(Object{}));   // ok?? calls foo<Object&>
foo(std::forward<Object&>(Object{})); // error
```

The first two cases lead to potentially modifying objects that were intended to be `const` (which could be UB if they were constructed `const`), the last case is passing a dangling lvalue reference.