# Why there are two signatures of std::forward?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, rvalue-reference, rvalue

As stated at [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/forward/), `std::forward` has two signatures:

```
template <class T> T&& forward (typename remove_reference<T>::type& arg) noexcept;
template <class T> T&& forward (typename remove_reference<T>::type&& arg) noexcept;
```

The typical use of `std::forward` is to preserve rvalueness while passing arguments to other functions. Let's illustrate this with an example:

```
void overloaded(int &)  { std::cout << "lvalue"; }
void overloaded(int &&) { std::cout << "rvalue"; }

template <typename T>
void fwd(T && t)
{
  overloaded(std::forward<T>(t));
}
```

When we call `fwd(0)`, `T` deduces to `int` (`t` has type `int &&`). Then we call `std::forward<int>(t)`. The result of that call is expression of type `int &&` so the second version of `overloaded` function is selected and the program prints "rvalue" to the standard output.

When we call `fwd(i)` (where i is some int variable), `T` deduces to `int&` (`t` has type `int &`). Then we call `std::forward<int&>(t)`. The result of that call (after applying reference collapsing rules) is expression of type `int &` so the first version of `overloaded` function is selected and the program prints "lvalue" to the standard output.

In both these cases we use the first overload of `std::forward` (the one taking `typename remove_reference<T>::type& arg`). It is because even if the type of `t` is `int &&` it binds to lvalue reference (because named variable of type "rvalue reference to something" is itself lvalue and lvalues can't bind to rvalue reference).

**Question 1:**

What is that second overload of `std::forward` for? Can you think of some practical example, that uses the overload taking `arg` by rvalue reference?

**Question 2:**

[cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/forward/) says:

> Both signatures return the same as:
>
> ```
> static_cast<decltype(arg)&&>(arg)
> ```

The problem I have with that, is that I'm pretty sure that it is wrong. When we try to return this from the first overload of `std::forward` we get a compilation error.

When `fwd` is called with `int` rvalue, it calls the first overload of `std::forward` with `T = int`. Then, `decltype(arg)` will become `int&` so `static_cast<decltype(arg)&&>(arg)` will collapse to `static_cast<int&>(arg)`. But the return type is `int &&` and we get compilation error:

```
cannot bind ‘std::remove_reference<int>::type {aka int}’ lvalue to ‘int&&’
```

Both overloaded versions of `std::forward` should return `static_cast<T&&>(arg)`. Am I right?

Do you think that the quote from cplusplus.com is a mistake?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38344332/why-does-stdforward-have-two-overloads for an answer to the first question.

Comment: @TartanLlama That one has a bunch of `const` and `const_cast` sprinked throughout tho.

Comment: `cplusplus.com` is NOT `cppreference`. `cppreference.com` is `cppreference`. Know the difference.

Comment: @Nawaz stating the difference may or may not be on topic (I find cppreference far more reliable, myself)

Comment: @Yakk: I dont even look at cplusplus.com, because of my experience: [What's wrong with cplusplus.com?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520052/whats-wrong-with-cplusplus-com)

Comment: @Yakk And if you find a bug you can always fix it yourself :)

Answer (score 1):

```
class Foo {};

auto f = [](){ return Foo{}; };
auto g = []()->Foo&{ static Foo x; return x; };

template<class T>
std::false_type is_rvalue( T& ) { return {}; }
template<class T>
std::true_type is_rvalue( T&& ) { return {}; }

template<class T, class F>
auto test( F&& f ) {
  return is_rvalue( std::forward<T>( f() ) );
}

int main() {
  std::cout << test<Foo>(f) << "," << test<Foo&>(g) << "\n";
}
```

It is a bit contrived; but imagine where you have some factory that might produce a `Foo` or a `Foo&` depending on some unimportant details, but you *know* you want to forward it based on a second type `T` to `T&&`.  You know that if `T` is not a reference, then it won't produce `Foo`, but if `T` is a reference it might.