# What is the use of forwarding an rvalue?

Tags: c++, templates, forwarding-reference

I'm reading the `std::forward` entry in [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward).

For the second overload of `std::forward`, there is an example:

> ```
> template<class T>
> void wrapper(T&& arg)
> {
>     foo(forward<decltype(forward<T>(arg).get())>(forward<T>(arg).get()));
> }
> ```
>
> where the type of `arg` may be
>
> ```
> struct Arg
> {
>     int i = 1;
>     int  get() && { return i; } // call to this overload is rvalue
>     int& get() &  { return i; } // call to this overload is lvalue
> };
> ```

But whether `forward<T>(arg).get()` is lvalue or rvalue can be distinguished without the use of `std::forward` (If the argument of `wrapper` referring to `arg` is lvalue, `forward<T>(arg).get()` is lvalue; otherwise it is rvalue). The following program is a support:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

struct Arg
{
    int i = 1;
    int  get() && { return i; } // call to this overload is rvalue
    int& get() &  { return i; } // call to this overload is lvalue
};

void foo(int&)  {std::cout << "lvalue\n";}
void foo(int&&) {std::cout << "rvalue\n";}

template<class T>
void wrapper(T&& arg)
{
    foo(std::forward<T>(arg).get()); // without the use of outer forward
}

int main()
{
    Arg arg;
    wrapper(arg);
    wrapper(static_cast<Arg&&>(arg));
}
```

[Running Result](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f2ffc3b37ae5ea8)

So what is the use of the outer `std::forward`?

Comment: I think this is simply a poorly written example, just to demonstrate the use of the second `std::forward` overload. As to why the second overload is needed, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38344332/why-does-stdforward-have-two-overloads.

Comment: I think when you have both `foo(int&)` and `foo(int&&)` implemented, there is no need here to use forward...

Comment: in my understanding `get() &&` should already return `int &&` and the use of `return std::move(i);` inside it is actually legit.

Comment: @Holt better example would be welcome (as long as it's not distractingly long)