# Second overload of std::foward (example on cppreference.com)

Tags: c++, c++11, perfect-forwarding

I know that the second overload of `std::forward`:

```cpp
template< class T >
constexpr T&& forward( std::remove_reference_t<T>&& t ) noexcept;
```

is used for rvalues (as stated by Howard Hinnant in his answer: [How does std::forward receive the correct argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29135698/#29135875))

There is an example of when this overload is used at [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) (that is also mentioned in [How does std::forward receive the correct argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29135698/#29135875) by Praetorian):

> 2. Forwards rvalues as rvalues and prohibits forwarding of rvalues as lvalues This overload makes it possible to forward a result of an expression (such as function call), which may be rvalue or lvalue, as the original value category of a forwarding reference argument.
>
> For example, if a wrapper does not just forward its argument, but calls a member function on the argument, and forwards its result:
>
> ```
> // transforming wrapper 
> template<class T>
> void wrapper(T&& arg)
> {
>     foo(forward<decltype(forward<T>(arg).get())>(forward<T>(arg).get()));
> }
> ```
>
> where the type of arg may be
>
> ```
> struct Arg
> {
>     int i = 1;
>     int  get() && { return i; } // call to this overload is rvalue
>     int& get() &  { return i; } // call to this overload is lvalue
> };
> ```

I really don't get this example. Why is the outer forward `forward<decltype(forward<T>(arg).get())>` even needed?

Cppreference states:

> This overload makes it possible to forward a result of an expression (such as function call), which may be rvalue or lvalue, as the original value category of a forwarding reference argument.

As an example:

```cpp
void func(int& lvalue)
{
    std::cout << "I got an lvalue!" << std::endl;
}

void func(int&& rvalue)
{
    std::cout << "I got an rvalue!" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
T&& myForward(typename std::remove_reference_t<T>& t)
{
    return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}

struct foo
{
    int i = 42;
    int& get()& { return i; }
    int get()&& { return i; }
};

template <typename T>
void wrapper(T&& t)
{

    func(myForward<T>(t).get());
}

int main()
{
    foo f;
    wrapper(f);
    wrapper(foo());

    return 0;
}
```

This prints:

```
I got an lvalue!
I got an rvalue!
```

just fine, without the outer forward, while it also forwards the "result of an expression [...] as the original value category of a forwarding reference argument." It does not even need the second overload of `std::forward`. This overload is only necessary when calling `func()` like this:

```cpp
func(myForward<decltype(myForward<T>(t).get())>(myForward<T>(t).get()));
```

Still, I can't wrap my head around why anyone would need to add the outer forward.

**Edit:** Edit moved to follow-up question: [RValue-reference overload of std::forward potentially causing dangling reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68667131/rvalue-reference-overload-of-stdforward-potentially-causing-dangling-reference)

Comment: You are quoting some unknown source.  Searching the link above the quote containing "example, if a wrapper does not" for that string does not show that string?  Is the "quoted" section above supposed to be a quote, or is it just misformatted?

Comment: Are you paraphrasing while pretending to quote?  Am I confused?  Did you drop the wrong link?

Comment: Ah, you are quoting https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward

Comment: It is probably just an example of what can happen in complicated template programming scenarios. To simplify even more: we probably want the code like `myForward<int>(42);` to compile, and it will not compile without `std::remove_reference_t<T>&& t` overload.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41543571/5376789

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is the outer forward `forward<decltype(forward<T>(arg).get())>` even needed?

[It's not](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Ay0de47R9Ei0Ln3q). The expression already is of its own correct value category. In C++17 (when returning by value bigger types) it's even a pessimization. All it does is turn a potential prvalue into an xvalue, [and inhibiting copy elision](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38043319/817643). I'm tempted to say it's cargo cult programming.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It made me have a closer look at the value categories involved in the full expression. Consequently, I wonder if the second overload of std::forward might cause dangling references when used with prvalues (see my edit).

Comment: @Ruperrrt - please read https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93513/317773

Comment: Thank you for highlighting that! Moved the edit to a follow-up question.