# RValue-reference overload of std::forward potentially causing dangling reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, pass-by-reference, perfect-forwarding, temporary-objects

This question is a follow-up question to: [Second overload of std::foward (example on cppreference.com)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68651800/second-overload-of-stdfoward-example-on-cppreference-com).

StoryTeller's answer made me think about the value categories involved in the statement `foo(forward<decltype(forward<T>(arg).get())>(forward<T>(arg).get()));`. Doesn't the second overload

```cpp
template< class T >
constexpr T&& forward( std::remove_reference_t<T>&& t ) noexcept;
```

potentially cause dangling references? Changing my example of the linked question to

```cpp
void func(int& lvalue)
{
    std::cout << "I got an lvalue!" << std::endl;
}

void func(int&& rvalue)
{
    std::cout << "I got an rvalue!" << std::endl;
}

// now according to the 2nd overload of std::forward
template <typename T>
T&& myForward(typename std::remove_reference_t<T>&& t)
{
    return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}

struct foo
{
    int i = 42;
    int& get()& { return i; }
    int get()&& { return i; }
};

// now with the inner and the outer forward as in the example on cppreference
template <typename T>
void wrapper(T&& t)
{

    func(myForward<decltype(myForward<T>(t).get())>(myForward<T>(t).get()));
}

int main()
{
    wrapper(foo());

    return 0;
}
```

made me think that there is already a dangling reference involved: `myForward<T>(t).get()` returns an `int` prvalue whose evaluation initializes a temporary object that `typename std::remove_reference_t<T>&& t` binds to when calling `myForward<decltype(myForward<T>(t).get())>(myForward<T>(t).get())`.
(According to cppreference, this conversion "[...] produces an xvalue denoting the temporary object." But what exactly is the **xvalue expression** when triggering a temporary materialization conversion by **binding a prvalue to a reference**? Is it even existent in the code? It's not `myForward<T>(t).get()` because that's a prvalue. Or is this prvalue converted to an xvalue by binding it to a reference in `myForard`?)

Next, `myFoward` returns an rvalue-reference `int&&` to this variable local to `myForward`, which the `int&&` of the `func()`-overload then binds to. Initially, I'd thought this already introduces a dangling reference, but then I read the paragraph "Lifetime of a temporary" of the article "Reference initialization" on [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization). There are "exceptions to this lifetime rule":

> "a temporary bound to a reference parameter in a function call exists until the end of the full expression containing that function call: if the function returns a reference, which outlives the full expression, it becomes a dangling reference."

In conclusion, this temporary object local to myForward exists up until the semicolon of the full expression — all good.
However, my interpretation of "if the function returns a reference, which outlives the full expression, it becomes a dangling reference" is "if the function returns a reference **to that reference parameter**". That should mean that changing `wrapper(T&& t)` like so

```cpp
template <typename T>
void wrapper(T&& t)
{

    // func(myForward<decltype(myForward<T>(t).get())>(myForward<T>(t).get()));
    int&& ref = std::forward<decltype(std::forward<T>(t).get())>(std::forward<T>(t).get());
    func(ref);
}
```

should result in ref being a dangling reference. Still, I can print "42" (the correct value) in `void func(int&& rvalue)`, even when putting some other values on the stack between binding to `int&& ref` and calling `func(ref)`. Also, printing the address of `t` in `myForward`, `ref` in `wrapper` and `rvalue` in `func` always gives the same value, which means it's the same object (local to `myForward`).

At the same time, that should mean that one is dealing with a dangling reference when calling the second overload of `std::forward` with a prvalue and not using the reference returned by it in the same expression. Or am I missing something regarding this topic?

Comment: That isn't the intended use of `std::forward` so I wouldn't be surprised if it lead to problems like dangling references. As far as I know, it is just meant to help implement perfect forwarding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Doesn't the second overload ... potentially cause dangling references?

If the argument is a non-dangling reference, then so will the returned reference be non-dangling. If the argument is a temporary, then the reference will become danging after the full-expression. I wouldn't say it has been "caused" by `std::forward`. If you're passing a prvalue to `std::forward`, then you're probably using it wrong.

> That should mean that changing wrapper(T&& t) like so ... should result in ref being a dangling reference.

Correct. `ref` is a dangling reference in that version.

> Still, I can print "42" (the correct value) in void func(int&& rvalue), even when putting some other values on the stack between binding to int&& ref and calling func(ref)

Congratulations. You're on your first step of learning what undefined behaviour means.

Comment: The process of learning about Undefined Behavior is eerily similar to the 5 stages of grief.

Comment: I thought I was missing some rule that made this defined behaviour. :D Thank you for your answer!