# How does the rvalue argument get through to the right forward function?

Tags: c++, perfect-forwarding

I'd really like to finally get to understand this. Let's say `std::forward` is defined like this:

```
template<class T>
T&& forward(typename std::remove_reference<T>::type& t) noexcept {
  return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}

template <class T>
T&& forward(typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&& t) noexcept {
  return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}
```

We have a function:

```
template <typename T>
void I_forward_arguments(T&& arg)
{
     forward<T>(arg);
}

I_forward_arguments(5);
```

I pass 5, which is an rvalue, and `T` in `I_forward_arguments()` is `int` type. It then calls `forward` with explicit template argument of `int`, meaning the call is no longer a deduced context and there are no universal references, and the two choices of functions to call are:

```
template<class T>
int&& forward(typename std::remove_reference<int>::type& t) noexcept {
  return static_cast<int&&>(t);
}

template <class T>
T&& forward(typename std::remove_reference<int>::type&& t) noexcept {
  return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}
```

which when we remove the reference we end up with one taking an `int&` and another taking an `int&&`. Since the argument in `I_forward_arguments` is ALWAYS an lvalue, I don't understand how it gets through to the function taking the `int&&` version of `forward`. Can someone please explain this? I've spent a long time trying to figure it out.

Comment: In your example, `forward<int>(int&)` is in fact called - which goes ahead and casts the lvalue to rvalue reference `int&&`. The result of this `forward` call is an rvalue, which is what really matters. Whether `forward` returns an lvalue or an rvalue doesn't depend on what its argument is, but on what its template parameter `T` is - whether it's a reference or a non-reference type.

Comment: IgorTandetnik Wait, why is 'arg' (the parameter name/identifier) an int& while T is an int? in void func(T&& arg); I pass it an rvalue, then T is 'int', and 'arg' is 'int' also, isn't it? T is 'int' and arg is 'int&'?

Comment: There is a trick to debug type deductions I usually use (maybe there is even more straightforward way with latest standard): declare incomplete template class: `template <typename T> struct S;` then try instantiate it: `S<T> s;` or `S<decltype(arg)> s;` and check the type in error messages in unclear scenarios.

Comment: As you yourself noted, `arg` is an lvalue of type `int`. Overload resolution then prefers a function taking `int&` over one taking `int&&`. But that makes no difference, as both overloads produce the same result anyhow - an `int&&` rvalue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Second overload of std::foward (example on cppreference.com)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68651800/second-overload-of-stdfoward-example-on-cppreference-com)

Answer (score 0):

int&& parameter here is lvalue (reference to rvalue t).

By the §3.10.1.4:

> An rvalue is an xvalue, a temporary object or subobject thereof, or a value that is not associated with an object.

Since t is not a temporary object, and it is associated with an object, it is an *lvalue*.